# Facebook Graph API explorer not showing one of my fanpages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

i am creating new access tokens for my fanpages and all of that works great. The only issue i have is that one of my fanpages does not show up in the graph api explorer at all. 
When i type in me/accounts i see all of my pages except for the one i am talking about.
Does anyone know where the problem could be?

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: How many pages do you have? Maybe you just need to paginate to the second page of results …?

Comment: Thank you CBroe. That was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, I think your page you don't see in the next page.

Try click at the link like picture below:

[image: Get next page]

Comment: That did it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it help :)